# Automatically generate invoice pdf and save to server when invoice is created

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, pdf, invoice-pdf

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'd like for Magento 2 to automatically create the invoice PDF and save it somewhere on the server when an invoice is generated/created.

Is this possible?

Magento 2.2.7

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is something "out-of-the-box" in Magento 2 for this.
But you can easily create an observer for the event `sales_order_invoice_register`. This event is called after a new invoice is created.
You can realize that with something like this:

**1. register observer in events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_order_invoice_register">
    <observer name="yourObserverName" instance="YourCompany\YourModule\Observer\YourObserver" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**2. create YourObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SavePdfInvoices implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_pdfInvoiceModel;
    protected $_outputDirectory;
    private $_myPdfStorageSubDirectory = "pdfinvoices";

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice $pdfInvoiceModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
        ) {
            $this->_pdfInvoiceModel = $pdfInvoiceModel;
            $this->_outputDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try{
            $order = $observer->getData('order');
            if (!$order->hasInvoices()){
               return $this;
            }
            $invoice =  $order->getInvoiceCollection()->getFirstItem();
            $pdfContent = $this->_pdfInvoiceModel->getPdf([$invoice])->render();
            //save to file wherever you want, in this example in var/pdfinvoices/[IncrementID].pdf
            $this->_outputDirectory->writeFile($this->_myPdfStorageSubDirectory. "/" . $invoice->getIncrementId() . ".pdf" ,$pdfContent);
        } catch (Exception $e){
            //some usefull exception handling if you need
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, it is working but with one bug. Invoice ID is missing in both the PDF file that is generated and the name of the pdf. It is saving as just .pdf and when opening the pdf invoice# at the top is empty

Comment: Sorry, I had a little bug in the code above, I've corrected it. The event `sales_order_invoice_register` doesn't provide the invoice object, but the order.
The initial code would work in the event `sales_order_invoice_save_after` but that would mean you regenerate the invoice on every save action. You can make that also.
So you have two choices: Change only the event to `sales_order_invoice_save_after` in your events.xml or change the execute method in YourObserver.php.

Comment: @HelgeB I'm getting error. 

`Invalid template file: 'Magento_Payment::info/pdf/default.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Braintree' block's name: 'info_0'`

Answer (score 0):

no dear its not working. Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  sales_order_invoice_save_after

please guide me at